# Hide Xcode Console Always

Tags: xcode, macos, console

Is there a way, in Xcode 10, to hide the console (output + debugger) area from popping up every time I run my app? I'm using another tab that I've detached as my console/debugger window, but on the tab that I'm using for coding I don't want the console constantly popping up. How can this be achieved?

I've tried changing the behaviour in the Preferences --> Behaviors menu, but that just hid the debugger, not the overall pane.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a possibility to trigger certain events when running/pausing/... your App in Xcode's preferences [preferences/behaviour]. Also hiding the debug area including the console. Otherwise [Command + Shift + Y] instantly closes the debug area, [Command + Shift + C] does the same with the console. [Picture of Xcode Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIhOZ.png)

Comment: I noticed that shortly after I posted this question. Thanks for the response.